# Automatic message to Telegram channel from website

Tags: html, telegram

I’m totally new to this. I would like to check if I am able to integrate automated telegram message to my telegram channel from my web site that allow users to make a post, similar to a forum based. This message is sent to my channel when a user make a post to my web site, and the message contain a link to my web site.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can use [Modir robot](https://t.me/modir_robot) to send your site feed (rss) to your channel automatically.

Comment: Lets say I’m using Wordpress on my website, i’ll be able to use Modir Robot to automatically send the feed to my telegram channel? Thank you so much for the response.

Comment: @NewbieToThis yes, you can add your site `feed` to the bot